# How to build a printf-style string for a image sequence in windows batch-files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

Is there a way, with a windows batch-file, to detect image sequences in a given folder and generate a string that represents it in a printf-style notation?

**For example:**

A directory contains 300 files named `S002_comp_v04.0000.exr` to `S002_comp_v04.0299.exr` and I need a string like `S002_comp_v04.%04d.exr`.

**Background:**

I want a batch file where i can drop any folder on and it processes the folder's contents in order to pass it on to ffmpeg for encoding. Easy with python - **but how to achieve that with windows batch-files only?** Windows version is 8.1 and 10.

Comment: Possible but not trivial, give it a try.

Comment: I am afraid  I don't understand your request. Given these two filenames as example `S002_comp_v04.0000.exr` and `S002_comp_v04.0299.exr`, what exactly are the output strings you want? Is `S002_comp_v04.%04d.exr`? For that, you just need _one_ file or eve none at all! You missed a core point, I think...

Comment: Hi @Aacini, yes `S002_comp_v04.%04d.exr` is the string i want. It represents a file sequence of unknown length, start and end but tells a software that there is a sequence and how its named and how the name is formatted. So basically I'm looking for a way to loop through the contents of a folder and detect files that are named identical except for the counting part of the name (in my case, it might be possible to take it for granted that the counter is separated with a point from the basename and the file-extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this question have several missing points, so I added they:

- In the folder there are *just* the files of *one* sequence string.
- The counter part in *all files* have the same lenght and start with zero.
- The counter is separated with a point from the basename and the file-extension.

The Batch file below create the requested string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the base name, the counter and the extension of first file
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B %1') do (
   set "basename=%%a"
   set "counter=%%b"
   set "ext=%%c"
   goto break
)
:break

rem Get the length of counter
for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do if "!counter:~%%i,1!" neq "" set /A len=%%i+1

echo %basename%.%%0%len%d.%ext%
```

Example:

```
C:\> dir theFolder /b
S002_comp_v04.0000.exr
S002_comp_v04.0299.exr

C:\> test.bat theFolder
S002_comp_v04.%04d.exr
```

Comment: Sorry, that my qustion was not clear enough - but your solution is really what I was looking for. I did not really believe that this is possible with a batch file. Thank you very much for your efforts!